# Wrong goal completion numbers

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have 10 goals set up in Google analytics. They all share the same completion URL, but all have different funnels / steps before completion.

Today I know that I have one goal completion, but looking at the report there is 10 reported. So completions are counted for all my goals.

Has anyone experienced the same and figured out a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The funnel steps apply only fo the funnel report. The Goal Completions are based only on the Goal Url. Hence if you have the same Goal Url for all of them you will have 10 Goal Completions no matter what are the steps you have setup for each one of them.

Comment: I did not know this. Well, that explains a lot. Thanks I'll try to add some parameter when redirecting to the goals page then.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a possibility to use a different completion url for all of them?

Comment: Guess I could throw some parameters on different completions and take it from there.